# Car Following Model with Optimal Velocity function - overtake occurence

Tags: python, math, simulation, traffic

I am creating a project on car simulations and I've run into a problem. When I run my code, the cars sometimes overtake one another.

I have spent few days trying to figure out why is this happening and I still have no idea. The optimal velocity function should set the (de)acceleration, so that the overtake would not happen, but for some reason, it still allows cars to sometimes overatake each other and not decelerate fast enough.

Could you help me, or just push me in direction where I should be looking ?

Here is my optimal velocity function:

```
def optimal_velocity_function(dx, d_safe, v_max):
vx_opt = v_max * (np.tanh(dx - d_safe) + np.tanh(d_safe))
return vx_opt
```

Now I am using it within Euler's method to solve ODE:

```
def euler_method(x, v, n_cars, h, tau, d_safe, v_max):
# Euler method used to solve ODE
# returns new position of car and its new velocity
dv = np.zeros(n_cars)

for j in range(n_cars - 1):
        dv[j] = tau ** (-1) * (optimal_velocity_function(x[j+1] - x[j],   d_safe, v_max) - v[j])

dv[n_cars - 1] = tau ** (-1) * (v_max - v[n_cars - 1])  # Speed of first car

v_new = v + h * dv
x_new = x + h * v_new

return [x_new, v_new]
```

And here is rest of the model, basically just generating starting values and then iterating using the functions above.

```
def optimal_velocity_model(n, n_cars, d_0, v_0, h, tau, d_safe, v_max):
global x_limit, canvas, xx, vv

car_positions = np.linspace(0, n_cars, n_cars)
x = np.array(sorted(np.random.random(n_cars) + car_positions))  # Generation of cars with minimal distance
x = x * d_0
v = np.random.random(n_cars) + v_0  # Generating initial speeds around v_0
xx = np.zeros([n_cars, n])  # Matrix of locations
vv = np.zeros([n_cars, n])  # Matrix of velocities

for i in range(n):
    xx[:, i] = x
    vv[:, i] = v
    [x, v] = euler_method(x, v, n_cars, h, tau, d_safe, v_max)

x_limit = xx.max()  # Interval in which will cars be
return
```

Thanks a lot. J.

Comment: Why do you add `+ np.tanh(d_safe)`? Why do you use `tanh` at all? Is there a reason or do you use it just because the function looks nice? Does the problem occur also if you decrease the time step length?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting a bit lost here into the maths and not focusing on the physics of the problem. By using the tanhh over `delta X` as well as the safe distance you are generating a soft SPEED transition that might not guarantee that overtaking is inhibited.

My train of thought would be something like:

- Firstly assess the relative speed of the two vehicles approaching the safety distance
- Define the minimum deceleration given the vehicle properties that can stop it within the distance
- Use the tanhh or any other function to model transition between
  aggressive to smooth braking or viceversa.
- Update your speed by integrating that acceleration.

To calculate the deceleration I can think of a simple approach to keep the use of tanh :

```
Deceleration=Max_Dec(relative_speed)*[1+tanh(d_safe-dx)]
```

Hope this can guide you further!